read all data blocks on postgres replica quickly
The goal is to - as quickly as the DB hardware allows - read all data blocks on a remote postgres read replica, without being limited by network bandwidth between my local PC and the DB. On a primary postgres DB, I achieve this via issuing (from my local PC) VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE, DISABLE_PAGE_SKIPPING, INDEX_CLEANUP, SKIP_DATABASE_STATS) for each table, in about twice as many sessions as the DB server has CPUs.
On a replica, I can't issue VACUUM. An option would be SELECT * on each table, done in parallel in several sessions, but that (a) causes unnecessary network transfer of all data (several terabytes) and (b) does not load all index data blocks.
How would one do that?
Background: Amazon RDS blue/green demands that all data blocks are read to 'speed up lazy loading' before the green DB can used at normal speeds: Handling lazy loading when you create a blue/green deployment
UPDATE VACUUM FULL of all tables on the primary should also do the trick to have 'read' all table and index blocks on the replica. This approach might be a lot slower though than reading all blocks on primary (via the non-full vacuum mentioned above) and separately reading all blocks on replica (via a to-be-found way).

pg_prewarm?

@mustaccio pg_prewarm seems to be a great suggestion. It can prewarm table data,  index blocks, toast data and toast indexes. Great! TYVM.

VACUUM FULL makes a copy of the table and the indexes on this table. It's reading from the "old" table while writing to the "new" table.

Using a single database connection, you can use a DO statement and loop over all tables.
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _row    RECORD;
    _sql    TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR _row IN SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        _sql    := FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %I.%I;', _row.table_schema, _row.table_name);
        EXECUTE _sql;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;


TY. This does not load the indexes though.

@Peter That's correct. The only way to do so, is to fire a ton of queries to the database that reads each part of the index, for every index on every table. Besides that, you need enough memory to keep it all in memory. One table with 3 indexes, would most likely need at least 3*3 queries to read all 3 indexes. This takes time.
